# how to minify html render in php mvc

Tags: php

I want to minimize html code dynamically when rendering

This is my view class and a page is rendered

```
public static function render($filePath, $data = array()){
        extract($data);
        ob_start();
        require_once("mvc/view/" . $filePath);
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        minifyContent($content);
        require_once("theme/default.php");
  }
```

I try to use this function to minimize

```
function minifyContent($content){

    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',  // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',  // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
        '/(\s)+/s'       // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
    );

    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );

    $content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
    return $content;
}
```

When I use this, only my content shrinks and repeats twice

How can I tell him to minify all the content, even the default template?

Comment: Why not just turn on server side content zipping?

Comment: @Justinas Tell me how it works and should be activated?

Comment: Depends on your web server, but most web servers have an option/module/setting to automatically compress responses. This is really something you shouldn't burden your application code with, as it's purely a transport-optimisation, which the web server or even proxies further downstream from it (like a CDN) can do transparently.

Comment: Just search for `{your server} compress response`. E.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+compress+response